Slurmctld: error: mysql_real_connect failed: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
I cannot resolve the following issue:
root@MyCluster:/opt/WorkLoadManager/slurm/23.11.5# systemctl status slurmctld
× slurmctld.service - Slurm controller daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/slurmctld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-04-09 16:18:33 CEST; 4s ago
    Process: 2592430 ExecStart=/opt/WorkLoadManager/slurm/23.11.5/sbin/slurmctld --systemd $SLURMCTLD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2592430 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 44ms

Apr 09 16:18:32 MyCluster.num.lab slurmctld[2592430]: slurmctld: Job accounting information stored, but details not gathered
Apr 09 16:18:32 MyCluster.num.lab slurmctld[2592430]: slurmctld: slurmctld version 23.11.5 started on cluster MyCluster
Apr 09 16:18:32 MyCluster.num.lab systemd[1]: Started Slurm controller daemon.
Apr 09 16:18:32 MyCluster.num.lab slurmctld[2592430]: slurmctld: accounting_storage/slurmdbd: clusteracct_storage_p_register_ctld: Registering slurmctld at port 6817 with slurmdbd
Apr 09 16:18:33 MyCluster.num.lab slurmctld[2592430]: slurmctld: priority/multifactor: _read_last_decay_ran: No last decay (/var/spool/slurmctld/priority_last_decay_ran) to recov>
Apr 09 16:18:33 MyCluster.num.lab slurmctld[2592430]: slurmctld: No memory enforcing mechanism configured.
Apr 09 16:18:33 MyCluster.num.lab slurmctld[2592430]: slurmctld: error: mysql_real_connect failed: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Apr 09 16:18:33 MyCluster.num.lab slurmctld[2592430]: slurmctld: fatal: You haven't inited this storage yet.
Apr 09 16:18:33 MyCluster.num.lab systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 09 16:18:33 MyCluster.num.lab systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


I am using mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.16-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper and I previously tried the following fix:
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWD';
MariaDB [(none)]> flush privileges;
MariaDB [(none)]> USE mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User        | Host      | plugin                |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| mariadb.sys | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| root        | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql       | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| slurm       | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| slurm       | system0   | mysql_native_password |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+
quit
#systemctl restart mariadb

But then I got slurmctld: error: mysql_real_connect failed: 1698 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' .
I am expecting slurmctld.service to be active as the other service slurmd and slurmdbd.

You define the root user with a password, and you didn't give this password to your service (given it's saying Using password: NO in the logs). So you just need to get back to this service documentation about how to configure the DB access I think.

The controller seems to be configured to use the slurmdbd service for accounting (accounting_storage/slurmdbd) yet it tries to access the MySQL database directly. I therefore guess the jobcomp/mysql plugin is active too. The error message seems to indicate that JobCompPass is not set.
You could therefore either

deactivate the jobcomp/mysql plugin as it is redundant with the accounting_storage/slurmdbd plugin; or
set JobCompPass to the password of the root MySQL user


it was actually due to Field JobCompType=jobcomp/mysql from slurm.conf.
After modifying this field to JobCompType=jobcomp/none, the slurmctld service is activated.
Thanks for your help!
Below is part of the slurm.conf if other people want to compare
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
AccountingStorageEnforce=limits
AccountingStorageHost=localhost
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
#AccountingStorageUser=
#AccountingStoreFlags=
#JobCompHost=
#JobCompLoc=
#JobCompParams=
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
## previously jobcomp/mysql
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux


